Ansible: how to explain that sometimes $HOME environment variable is set and sometimes not?
With ansible it seems that sometimes the following code will work as expected:
- name: "copy some script"
  become: yes
  become_user: "{{ tomcat_user }}"
  ansible.builtin.copy:
    src: myscript.sh
    dest: $HOME/

but sometimes on some servers it will do nothing, as if $HOME was incorrectly set, but there is no error, just the file is not copied.
But if I change my code with the following, it will work each time I execute it:
- name: "copy some script"
  become: yes
  become_user: "{{ tomcat_user }}"
  ansible.builtin.copy:
    src: myscript.sh
    dest: /home/{{ tomcat_user }}/

I tried to debug with this code:
- name: "display debug info about $HOME"
  become: yes
  become_user: "{{ tomcat_user }}"
  ansible.builtin.debug:
    msg: "{{ lookup('ansible.builtin.env', 'HOME') }}"

And it gave me '/home/ansible' as a result. But I don't know if it takes into account the become_user or not... Because I'm almost sure that sometimes the HOME environment variable is set to the home of the become_user.
Do you have any idea if the HOME environment variable is sometimes set correctly to the HOME of the become_user, and sometimes not? And if this is the case how to explain it?

No, lookups do not use the become system.  So expressions like  lookup('env')  are run as the user running ansible-playbook.  Actually, the only thing become can affect is modules, and they are run in another shell.
Ideally, a script does not assume where a user's home directory is, so things work on different systems.  root home in /root is only the most obvious example.
Ansible attempts to do shell expansion on path type module parameters. That tilde syntax:
- copy:
    dest: "~{{ tomcat_user }}"

Or, if you collect facts with become, the user related ones are as the become user.  This style requires the home directory to either be the ansible user or the become user. Which does work for a lot of use cases.
- copy:
    dest: "{{ ansible_facts.user_dir }}"

